# Unable to remove tableitem from table in swt

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, set, swt

When i select List5 from left_group_table(List), all the items that belong to List5 should be removed from the middle_group_table(Contact). If the list contains mulitple items, all the items in the contact table should be removed. Please find the screenshot of the application and code snippet below. Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
public static ArrayList<String> allEmailsFortheSelectedList = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> allEmailsForALLSelectedList;

tableCursor.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
            final int selectionIndex = left_group_table.getSelectionIndex();

            if(left_group_table.getItem(selectionIndex).getChecked()) {
                int tempCount = 0;
                left_group_table.getItem(selectionIndex).setChecked(false);
                TableItem[] items = middle_group_table.getItems();

                if(allEmailsForALLSelectedList.containsKey(selectionIndex)) {
                    allEmailsForALLSelectedList.remove(selectionIndex);
                }

                Set<Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>>>  set = allEmailsForALLSelectedList.entrySet();
                Iterator<Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>>> itr = set.iterator(); 
                while(itr.hasNext()) 
                { 
                    HashMap.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry = itr.next(); 
                    for(int i=0; i< entry.getValue().size(); i++) {
                        new TableItem(middle_group_table, SWT.NONE);
                        items[tempCount].setText(1, entry.getValue().get(i));
                        tempCount++;
                    }
                }

                tempCount = items.length;
                middle_group_table.setRedraw(true);

            }else {
                int middleGroupTableItemCount = 0;
                left_group_table.getItem(selectionIndex).setChecked(true);
                sendEmailslistName = left_group_table.getItem(selectionIndex).getText(1);

                int listId = SelectionDb.getUserContactListId(sendEmailslistName);

                allEmailsForALLSelectedList.put(selectionIndex, SelectionDb.getAllContactEmail(listId));

                for (int i = 0; i < SelectionDb.getAllContactEmail(listId).size(); i++) {
                    new TableItem(middle_group_table, SWT.NONE);
                }

                middle_group_table.setRedraw(true);

                TableItem[] items = middle_group_table.getItems();
                Set<Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>>>  set = allEmailsForALLSelectedList.entrySet();
                Iterator<Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>>> itr = set.iterator(); 
                while(itr.hasNext()) 
                { 
                    HashMap.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry = itr.next(); 
                    for(int i=0; i< entry.getValue().size(); i++) {
                        items[middleGroupTableItemCount].setText(1, entry.getValue().get(i));
                        middleGroupTableItemCount++;
                    }
                }
                middleGroupTableItemCount = items.length;
            }

        }
```

Comment: So what are you actually asking? `Table` has a number of remove methods, where are you trying to use them?

Comment: I want to remove the entire row in the right table that belongs to List5 in left table

Comment: @Kutty The code snippet that you have provided is _very_ incomplete. Please provide a [mcve] to reproduce the issue - that would be something we can drop into an IDE and run without having to guess what we're missing from the code above.

Comment: To remove all row from table `removeAll` method should be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be removeAll() method for your table, that you can use.

middle_group_table.removeAll();

EDIT:
To remove a single row you need to get the right index of the element you want to remove, the simplest method without any LINQis this:

```
First get the right list you need:
List<String> itemsToRemove = ...getting the list5, from your code I don't understand how the list is holding.

Then you can just iterate in reverse way and remove.
for (int i = middle_group_table.getItemCount() - 1; i <= 0; i--)
{
    if (itemsToRemove.contains(items[i].getText()))
        middle_group_table.remove(i);
}
```

Comment: I just want to remove only one row from the table